# Is the sentence "I picture typical hotel doormen as standing outside the front entrance" grammatical?

Tags: grammar

An ELL post says

> I picture typical hotel doormen as standing outside the front entrance.

I am aware that "picture" here means "to imagine something", `picture sb as sb else`.

I am also aware that "standing outside ..." is participle.

I don't understand why is "standing outside ..." immediately after "as". Could someone please give a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern used here is *picture `someone` as `something`*.

https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/picture gives this example:

> Rob had pictured her as **serious**, but she wasn’t like that.

***Serious***, as well as ***standing outside the front entrance***, and ***having a blast***, and ***not being able to string a sentence together*** all lend themselves to this role of `something` in this case.

Comment: Thank you. **serious** is actually an adjective in ldoceonline's example, right?

Comment: @WXJ96163 Yes. That's a bit confusing I think, but yeah. In this case it fits. Adjectives, nouns, and *nouny* forms.

Comment: Thank you. Would I consider your answer as a YES to the question in my OP?

Comment: @WXJ96163 Of course, it's completely grammatical and idiomatic.